# join query and group_by

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join, group-by

i have two tables 'city' and 'info'. City looks like

```
                  city_id    name
                   1         c1
                   2         c2
```

And the info looks like

```
                  id   city_city_id   status_status_id
                  1     1              1
                  2     2              1
                  3     1              2
```

In the info table City_city_id and status_status_id are fks. I want to run a query that would count the number of cities under a particular status. For that i have joined the two tables and for each row of the 'city' table I've run a query but all the time i get the answer 00. That means it always shows number of city is zero under a particular status.

The model is give below :

```
            function count(){
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('city');
           $this->db->join('info','info.city_city_id= city.city_id');
           $this->db->group_by('city_city_id');
           $sql=$this->db->get();
           if ($sql->num_rows()>0){ 

          foreach ($sql->result() as $row){ //loops through all the cities in city table
          $r=1;

      $this->db->where('city_city_id','city.city_id');

       $this->db->where('status_status_id', $r);
      echo $this->db->count_all_results('info');


}
```

I think there is something wrong with my join and group_by but i can't find the fault.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to

```
I want to run a query that would count the number of cities 
under a particular status.
```

ie., You need the status, and number of cities belonging to that status. Right? Then the following SQL query will  work for you:

```
SELECT status_status_id, count( * ) AS num_cities
FROM info
GROUP BY status_status_id
```

Will give the result:

```
status_status_id    num_cities
       1                2
       2                1
```

Then, you may use something like this:

```
function count() {
    $this->db->select('status_status_id, count( * ) AS num_cities', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('info');
    $this->db->group_by('status_status_id');

    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        echo 'STATUS_ID : ' . $row->status_status_id . "\n";
        echo 'NUM_CITIES: ' . $row->num_cities . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please indicate which place of my code i should replace this.. thanks

Comment: @user1052462 I edited my answer with `count()` function's code. I don't know codeigniter, and what I provided here is by referring the documentation. So, there may be some syntax errors, but it shows my logic anyway.